# Setup osxcross to build iOS APP in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: ios, linux, cordova, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm currently working on a project based on Cordova. Nevertheless, I'm urged to set up GitLab CD to deliver our iOS or Android APP to the client as soon as possible. I've complete GitLab CD pipeline for the Android app, and I have a hard time grappling with the CD pipeline for iOS, and that's why I'm here to ask about.

Before we step into the problem I met, the following is my final goal to achieve:
Build the iOS APP in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS machine without using a virtual one, so that I can build a docker image to host the whole GitLab CD process which is based on the Linux system.

First came into my mind is to construct an image that is compatible for us to build an iOS app. After I've surveyed for a long time, I found an open-source project seemed to be my rescue -- [osxcross](https://github.com/tpoechtrager/osxcross), which aims to provide a well working OS X cross-toolchain for Linux, FreeBSD, OpenBSD and Android (Termux). sS such, I installed that toolchain following with the readme, resulting in the embarrassing situation as followed:

```
 DONE  Build complete. The src-cordova/www directory is ready to be deployed.
 INFO  Check out deployment instructions at https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/deployment.html

 INFO  executing "cordova clean ios" in folder /home/f26401004/Documents/kyronus/frontend/src-cordova
Running command: xcodebuild -project Kryonus.xcodeproj -configuration Debug -alltargets clean
osxcross: error: xcodebuild: unknown argument: '-project'
xcodebuild: Command failed with exit code 2
 INFO  executing "cordova build ios --release" in folder /home/f26401004/Documents/kyronus/frontend/src-cordova
cordova-custom-config: Skipping auto-restore of config file backup(s)
Command failed: xcrun simctl list --json
osxcross: warning: xcrun: ignoring environment variable 'DEVELOPER_DIR'
osxcross: error: xcrun: cannot find 'simctl' executable
```

It seems that xcrun do not recognize simctl argument? And here is how I built the osxcross:

1. `git clone [https://github.com/tpoechtrager/osxcross](https://github.com/tpoechtrager/osxcross)`
2. `cd osxcross`
3. `./build_clang.sh`
4. Download Xcode 11.3.1: https://developer.apple.com/download/more
5. `./tools/gen_sdk_package.sh <path_to_xcode_xip_file>`
6. Copy or move the SDK file into the `tarballs/` directory of OSXCross.
7. `UNATTENDED=1 ./build.sh`
8. Add the path of build result to env PATH

I am convinced that osxcross seemed to work well since that I did create a `test.cpp` file printing `Hello World`, compiling into an executable file, which successfully executed at a true Mac OS machine.

---

Therefore, I wondered whether I can fix such a problem by using xcodebuild directly without triggering Cordova command line to build my iOS APP. Nonetheless, It came out that my xcodebuild seemed to be useless, which only provided -version flag for developers.

```
f26401004@f26401004-PE62-7RD:~/Documents/kyronus/frontend$ xcodebuild
Only '-version' is supported by this stub tool
f26401004@f26401004-PE62-7RD:~/Documents/kyronus/frontend$
```

Hence, I tried to use [xcbuild](https://github.com/facebook/xcbuild) which is an Xcode-compatible build tool with the goal of providing faster builds, better documentation of the build process, and running on multiple platforms (macOS, Linux, and Windows) to directly build my iOS APP. But still failed.

```
** BUILD FAILED **

The following build commands failed:
    ProcessPCH /home/f26401004/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Kryonus-gaiqundnpwcugadckbjklitdwnad/Build/Intermediates/CordovaLib.build/Release-iphoneos/CordovaLib.build/PrefixHeaders/CordovaLib-5924aa2d2a574b697e53874f62fe1f5a/CordovaLib_Prefix.pch.pch CordovaLib_Prefix.pch normal armv7 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(1 failure)
f26401004@f26401004-PE62-7RD:~/Documents/kyronus/frontend$
```

Here are my steps to build xcbuild:

1. `git clone --depth=1 https://github.com/facebook/xcbuild`
2. `cd xcbuild`
3. `git submodule update --init`
4. `make`

---

I have no idea what to do next to make it to build iOS APP successfully on my com, or should I just give up and use a Mac OS Machine as GitLab runner to host CD process? I am willing to hear any advice to get different insight about it! Thx!